# How to organize or structure classes in Java?

Tags: java, architecture

I am a PHP web developer, organising my source code with MVC where all the web pages are in the Views, the business logics are in the Models, and Controllers handles users' requests, pass the right models to the right views. I am starting working with Java. What I know so far is BCE, which is similar to MVC. B (Boundary) contains GUIs, C (Controllers) and E (Entity contains all the models and models can represent database tables).

How to organise source code in Java, comparing to MVC in PHP? Is the following answer correct to this question?

In Java, source code be organised in layers:

```
 - presentation layer
 - service layer
 - data access layer
```

Is organising source code about system architectures?

Comment: I prefer package-by-feature style: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=205

Answer (score 3):

Organising code is about software architecture and doesn't depend on the language. That said MVC, layers, service orientation, micro services etc. are all viable architectures and the choice would depend on your needs/projects.

As with everything there's often no single correct way so start with what you feel most comfortable with. When you gain more experience you'll probably see room for improvement but I'd suggest to start simple and learn on the way.

As for package structure: you'd normally map one aspect of your architecture to packages which could be subsystems, features, layers, etc. Again the choice depends on your preference, project and needs. At work we are using feature/module + layer but that's just one way that works for us.

Answer (score 1):

The MVC structure is also a viable organization of your classes in java.
You can also use the [SOA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture) architecture for multi-tier Services-oriented applications. In fact, the choice really depends on your need.